# Mongoose Find Callback Not Executing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been slowly converting a callback-heavy module to use promises (Q) and I'm hitting a strange issue with Mongoose Models running `find()`. In brief, the promise chain was never getting past the initial `find` command. I've since reverted this method to its callback implementation and am still seeing no callback execution. I've broken it down to its most basic behavior and the `handleMedia` function is never running.

```
function getMediaByURL(url) {
  Media.find({url: url}, handleMedia);

  function handleMedia(err, media) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(media);
  }
}
```

The DB connection is being created in another module, but I'm seeing all of the right things initialize in the correct order, and the `readyState` of the Mongoose connection is `1` immediately before the `find` function is executed. If I convert the `find` method to a promise using `q.nbind` as described [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnbindnodemethod-thisarg-args) and log the value on a 1 second interval, the value is always `{state: 'pending')`.

I have another model that's saving over the same connection just fine with the promise version of `find`. I'm at a loss.

Comment: having a very similar issue, callback is not triggered even though readyState is 1. any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

you declared "handleMedia function" after "find function" ,so only the callback function is not called.. in your code first find function is executed after that "handleMedia function" is initialized

so try this

```
function getMediaByURL(url) {
    function handleMedia(err, media) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(media);
    }
    Media.find({url: url}, handleMedia);
}
```

Comment: This is actually completely false. Javascript uses something called "hoisting", basically this means that all the function keywords will be processed before and hoisted to the top of the scope, making the order of your code irrelevant.
Or atleast the order you declare and call functions in.